# how to align text in textarea in html

Tags: php, textarea

I have a `textarea` and I am also writing some PHP code to prefill the `textarea` upon refresh. The "prefill" part is working fine.

My problem is when I start to type in the `textarea`, the text is not left aligned. It is starting at some random point in the `textarea` box. I want it left aligned like a normal text box.

Here is my code:

```
<TEXTAREA rows = 10 cols = 95 name = answer5>
<?php echo stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['answer5'])); ?>
</TEXTAREA>
```

Comment: The reason for this might be because I am not closing the </textarea> right after it has started. But where else should I place my <php> code? I need to place the php code in between the <textarea> tags for the php code to work (pre fill)

Comment: Check for space characters in the text area.

Comment: Check for space characters in your php code as well

Comment: Yea, if the second line (with php code) and third line (closing textarea) are indented, that indentation will show in textarea as whitespace. Try putting them all on one line.

Comment: With your cursor in the textarea, press `ctrl+a` to select everything or right click and `Select All`. Is it highlighting a lot of whitespace? Try deleting everything in the textarea and see if the cursor is still aligned oddly.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn :  Thanks... placing all the 3 statements in a single line worked perfectly...Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 2 things:

- put all on 1 line
- trim the echoed value

So like this

```
<TEXTAREA rows = 10 cols = 95 name = answer5><?php echo trim(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['answer5']))); ?></TEXTAREA>
```

This because the textarea has some special rules that defy (as I call it) the normal markup rules. Never really understood it. But data inside textarea is always used as is, including leading and multiple spaces, etc. Even html comments inside textareas will be outputted.

Comment: please help me to figure out this, i have tried it but my data appear after 5 rows blank.my data is coming from data base, i also tried <?php echo trim(stripslashes(htmlentities($_POST['dta']))); ?> but my result is same.

Comment: hey man, you did a great job adding *put all on 1 line,  Its work for me

Answer (score 3):

Trimming is not a best option to go with.

It will trim all the spaces which are even needed.
I had the same problem and what I did was made all the code in a single line.

It depends on the spaces which you have in your text. My code was sometime like this before

```
<div class="controls">
<textarea name="about" class="span12" id="terms" rows="5">
<?php include('includes/terms.php');?>
</textarea>
</div>
```

Now output which I was getting was like this:

```
       Terms and Conditions

Point one
Point two
Point 3

Last Paragraph

// Here was huge space right at the bottom of textbox
```

So what is did was, modified my code this way:

```
<div class="controls"><textarea name="about" class="span12" id="terms" rows="5"><?php include('includes/terms.php');?></textarea></div>
```

Now everything is in single line and the spaces and new line entries which were there before are now gone. My text was printed like:

```
Terms and Conditions

Point one
Point two
Point 3

Last Paragraph

// Huge space is gone
```

You should also check the spaces which are there in the text contained in textarea element, apart from starting and ending points.

Answer (score 0):

The textarea tag might be inheriting a style that centers the text. You can add a style to the textarea to align it left. i.e.

```
<TEXTAREA style='text-align:left;' rows = 10 cols = 95 name = answer5>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea {
border: 1px solid #ddd;
background: #fff url(../img/input-shaddow.gif) no-repeat left top;
font: 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #000;
padding: 5px;
width: 262px;
float: left;
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
height: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

**the solution is easy put everything in one Line: ** `<textarea>votre addresse</textarea>`

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZwqw.png)